# Firebase reading issue. Object always null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a method which should initialize my field variable `currentTask`. I don't understand why I can't read my object from firebase. Here is the method:

```
private void getCurrentTask() {
    final DatabaseReference dRef1 = database.getReference().child("Users").child(uid).child("CurrentTask");
    dRef1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                currentTask = dataSnapshot.getValue(CurrentTask.class);
            } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(TasksListActivity.this, "no magic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });

    if (currentTask == null) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "magic)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Toast `no magic` never appears, so the object exists. But, in the end of the method toast `magic` appears, which means `currentTask == null`. Even after initialization!

And here is my database:

[image]

Comment: Where you get uid? Also, instead of toasting everywhere, try to learn how to debug your app - you can set breakpoint where program will stop and inspect what's the result from firebase.

Comment: @Gudin i get uid in OnCreate() of my activity. Only after that i call this method.

Comment: @Maxgmer, `currentTask` will always be `null` because `onDataChange` is asynchronous.

Comment: @JPVentura oh, that means that i should include all my code that uses `currentTask` into `onDataChange`? Or are there any other ways to cope with this issue?

Comment: Have you set correctly the authentication step, to access your database?

Comment: @Maxgmer, correct. You should include all code that uses `currentTask` into `onDataChange`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Roasario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41505442/4112725) and [@ReazMurshed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41505519/4112725) 's answer is both right. But let me make it more simple by describing how your code doesn't work as you expected:

```
private void getCurrentTask() {
    ...
    dRef1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ... (point 1)
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });

    ... (point 2)
}
```

Firebase Database load your data asyncronously. It means (to make it simple) that the process of getting data does not interfere with your main process. With that in mind, the code in `(point 2)` does not always get executed after code in `(point 1)`, and vice versa. Though usually code in `(point 1)` get executed after `(point 2)`, it is not always like that. So you should consider that the code you write in `(point 1)` can be executed at anytime.

Then you should write your code with that concept. Meaning that if you want to do anything to a variable inside `(point 1)` (like filling currentTask with dataSnapshot value then check if it is null), you should place it all inside `(point 1)`

Hope this help.

Comment: _Point 2_ is **always** executed after because is defined immediately after calling `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. The callback `onDataChange` is asynchronous and will take at least 4 milliseconds to run.

Comment: I think so too, but I'm not really sure. Thanks a lot for the info :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that onDataChange is asynchronous, so your if statement will always return false because you're checking if it is null while the data hasn't been read before. You should check if it is null inside of onDataChange (to assure the data has been read) like this:

```
private void getCurrentTask() {
    final DatabaseReference dRef1 = database.getReference().child("Users").child(uid).child("CurrentTask");
    dRef1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                currentTask = dataSnapshot.getValue(CurrentTask.class);

    if (currentTask == null) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "magic)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
            } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(TasksListActivity.this, "no magic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer.

Comment: Edited @ReazMurshed

Answer (score 2):

Modify your reference url a bit like this.

```
final DatabaseReference dRef1 = database.getReference().child("Users").child(uid);
```

Now create a class to represent each of your nodes.

```
public class User {
    public UserCharacter Character;
    public UserCurrentTask CurrentTask;    
    public String Email;
    public UserTasks Tasks;
}
```

Now inside your `onDataChange` you need to do this.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        User mUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        currentTask = mUser.CurrentTask;
    } else {
        // Show toast or something.
    }
}
```

And as @Roasario stated, the `onDataChanged` function is `Async`. So you can't get the actual value while you check for `null` value.

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach because he would be downloading the whole User node when he only needs the currentTask.

Comment: you mean i should load everything and work with the data i got inside `onDataChange`? That toasts are for you just to ease the explanation of the issue.

Comment: It actually loads the data of a single node. So it won't do any harm I guess unless the `CurrentTask`, `Tasks`, `Character` are huge objects. If they are large enough to be worried about then you need to rethink about your data structure I guess.