# How to make sure every related Firebase data have completely loaded?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

> **Disclaimer**: I made this question and answer it myself because I need a "bigger board" to answer extended question of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42448505/4112725) (as this whole explanation is never going to fit in comment

I'm having this data:

```
{
    "users" : {
        "randomUserId" : {
            "books" : {
                "booksId1" : true,
                "booksId2" : true
            }
        }
    },
    "books" : {
        "booksId1" : {
            "title" : "Awesome Book"
        },
        "booksId2" : {
            "title" : "Harry Potter"
        }
    }
}
```

I know I have to get `users/randomUserId/books` first then loop the `dataSnapshot` result to get all the book ids. Then I have to request detail data on each book id by using database reference that point to `books/bookId?/`. Something like this:

```
rootRef.child("users/" + user.getUid() + "books").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    ... onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot bookIdSnapshot : dataSnapshot) {
            rootRef.child("books/" + bookIdSnapshot.getValue(String.class))
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...) {
                    // here i get the book detail data
                }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

But with that code, each `rootRef.child("books/"...)` will be executed separately. So how can I know if the data have completely acquired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we only need an `int` or `double` to indicate if full all related data is completely loaded, but we also need to use those data right? So it's better to use `Map` or `HashMap` instead.

```
int bookTotalCount = -1;
HashMap<String, Book> bookMap = new HashMap<String, Book>();

rootRef.child("users/" + user.getUid() + "books").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    ... onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        bookTotalCount = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        for (DataSnapshot bookIdSnapshot : dataSnapshot) {
            rootRef.child("books/" + bookIdSnapshot.getValue(String.class))
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    ... onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Book book = dataSnapshot.getValue(Book.class);
                        bookMap.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), book);

                        if (bookMap.size() == bookTotalCount) {
                            // you can place code here
                            // in here, all the related data will be completely loaded
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

> Note: `Book` is a custom object created to contain data/value inside `books/bookId?`