# Android: Function returns the value before the value is updated from firebase help me out to return the updated value

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, listener, return-value

```
public String retrive(DatabaseReference myRef,String Tag) {         
     myRef = myRef.child(Tag);
     myRef1=myRef;
     String [] Value = new String[1];
     myRef1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             Value[0] = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class).toString();
          }
          @Override             public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
          }
      });
     return Value[0];
 }
```

In this above code, I want to get the updated value of the variable `value[0]` but the function returns `NULL` before the `EventListener` updates the value of the variable.

Comment: I've encounter so many question like this, here is [my latest answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42695655/4112725) to help you out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Return boolean value relative Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42690851/android-return-boolean-value-relative-firebase)

Comment: I didn't get solution from your above links if you have any answers plz help me

Comment: Please take your time to try understand it, because it is almost exact same case. The only different is it use `boolean` while you use `String`

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it like this. There is another way of doing this which is a better way imo. Change your function like this:

- Make it return `void`
- Add another parameter of type ValueEventListener
- Pass the event listener wherever you call this method

Changed function:

```
public String retrive(DatabaseReference myRef,String Tag, ValueEventListener listener) {         
         myRef = myRef.child(Tag);
         myRef1=myRef;
         myRef1.addValueEventListener(listener);
     }
```

After that when you want to call your function to get the value you may replace the code (which I assume you wrote) from:

```
String value = retrive(ref, tag);
```

To:

```
String value; // this is a field in your class
...
retrive(ref, tag, new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class).toString();
                 doSomethingWithValue(value); // you pass the value to another method and access it in that method
              }
              @Override             public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
              }
          }};
```

Then you define a method to access that value after it has been assigned with the value:

```
public void doSomethingWithValue(String value) {
    //here you access the value after it has been assigned
}
```

Comment: I Updated my code as you said but still when I access the variable *value* I don't receive the updated value

Comment: Can i see the code where you call the method and access the value? @dhrumitpatel

Comment: @dhrumitpatel I updated my code. I think you're good to go now.